# Input Elements Showing up First

Tags: html

I don't know why the `input` elements are showing up in the first row even though I placed them on the second row.

```
<body>    
    <h1>Fill out Your Time-card</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Monday</td>
            <td>Tuesday</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type=text id="monday"/>
            <input type=text id="tuesday"/>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ugrWP/

Comment: Always validate your HTML. It will show you mistakes like this one.

Comment: Validate your markup by using http://validator.w3.org :D

Comment: sorry for being dumb here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalid markup inside your table. You need to include the `<td>...</td>` tags for each cell in your `<tr>` rows. Like this:

```
<body>    
    <h1>Fill out Your Time-card</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Monday</td>
            <td>Tuesday</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type=text id="monday"/></td>
            <td><input type=text id="tuesday"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```